# Cannot find include for limits.h when building a GCC Cross-Compiler

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, x86-64, include-path, sparc

I want to build a cross-compiler with host type Linux x86_64 and `--target=sparc-sun-solaris2.10`.

I have successfully built binutils with `--target` flag along with GMP, MPFR and MPC.

I have configured Binutils and GCC to use `--with-build-sysroot=$SYSROOT` flag and recursively copyied over

- `/usr/include`
- `/lib`
- `/usr/lib`

from target host to it so that my `$SYSROOT` directory contains `usr` and `lib`.

I also set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my prefix before I build GCC.

But when I try to build GCC it fails trying to build libgcc (second stage I believe) with error:

`gcc/include-fixed/limits.h:169:61: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h`

I have verified that `limits.h` does exist in `$SYSROOT/usr/include` so why doesn't GCC use it?

Please help on this.

It will save our big company lots of man hours on if I can get cross-compilation of our code to work on x86_64. The performance is lightning fast on x86_64 compared to SPARC and compilation wait times is a big bottleneck for our productivity.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into a case of your [sysroot value getting set incorrectly](http://www.mail-archive.com/gcc@gcc.gnu.org/msg38085.html). You should probably try building with verbose options... as it would probably reveal that.